# how to upload image from mongoose schema to mongodb?

Tags: mern

Hi all i am new to **MERN Stack Development**. So please tell me how to upload a image from mongoose to **mongodb**. And also i need to know how to get the image path dynamically??.

Please suggest me some docs so that i can understand the concepts by depth. I have searched all over internet but i couldn't find what i needed.But i don't want to use "fs" in here. I need another way to upload the image.

This is my model

```
var list = new User({
    Name: "sri",
    Age: 11
    list.image.data=fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);
    list.image.contentType='image/png';   
    list.save()    
})
```

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?